# Does そよ have a negative, or any, connotation?

Tags: connotation

Sorry to ask such a trivial question as this. 予め、お詫び申し上げます。

I've recently created just a few social media accounts with the prefix "soyo____". Now, if I were to start communicating with Japanese people using such account names, does "soyo" have any connotation at all? I'm familiar with "そよ風" (but I chose "soyo" based on randomness really). Sorry to ask in this forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そよ (or そよそよ) is basically an onomatopoeia/mimesis that describes a mild wind or the sound of it. You can say 風がそよそよと吹く or 風がそよとも吹かない. そよ風 is from this そよ. Thus そよ may give an impression of "breezing" or "mild" if used as part of a Japanese-sounding name. On the other hand, something like *soyorx* (your account name) does not look like a Japanese word at all, and no one would care in such cases.